# Jquery array querying not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I have to pares through an array and it's multiple variables and input them on separate lines. 
Here is the code:

```
while (array[x] != null) {
            y = 0;
            y = x;
            alert(y + 'y');
            setTimeout(function() {
                if (y == 0 || y % 3 === 0) {
                    var namestring = array[y];
                    var namestring = namestring.replace('[','');
                    var namestring = namestring.replace('[','');
                    var namestring= namestring.replace('"', '');
                    var namestring= namestring.replace('"', '');    
                }
                if (y % 2 != 0 || y % 3 != 0 && x > 0) {
                    var date = array[y]
                    var date = date.replace('"', '');
                    var date = date.replace('"', '');
                }
                if (x % 2 == 0 && x > 0) {
                    var text = array[y];
                    var text = text.replace('"', '');
                    var text = text.replace('"', '');
                    var text = text.replace("]", '');
                    var text = text.replace("]", '');

                    createcard(namestring,date,text);
                }
            }, 500);
            if (x > 500) {
                break;
            };  
            x++;
            alert(x + 'x');
        }
```

The alerts are simply for debugging. Anyway, my variables, for example namestring gets returned as undefined. However, if I change the line to say array[0] instead of array[y], it works, even if y is set to 0...

Comment: would you mind if you added the `jQuery` array that is not working you've mention? I don't see any jQuery with the codes you posted

Comment: whats the input and sample output you want to accomplish?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon on line 18,   var date = array[y]

Comment: There's quite a bit going on here, I'm echoing @OliSoproniB., I think anyone would need to know your input/output requirements to begin to help you here.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning

y = 0;
and 
y = x;

x appears to be undefined in that code snippet but maybe it is part of a larger batch of code. It basically looks like you're overwriting y with the value of x?